# Why do the IE and Chrome display different content?

Tags: google-chrome, http, internet-explorer, web, go

I write a simple `Go` web server which just returns the path to web client:

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

type httpServer struct {
}

func (server httpServer) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte(r.URL.Path))
}

func main() {
    var server httpServer
    http.Handle("/", server)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:9000", nil))
}
```

Use `IE` web browser, it displays OK:
[image]

But the `Chrome` always redirect another site:
[image]

I doubt it is related to proxy. But why `IE` is OK, while `Chrome` not? I think they should use the same proxy.

Comment: Are you certain you are typing the same URL into Chrome as you did into IE?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:Yes.

Comment: I'm not a Go expert, so the only advice I can give you is to check the Go server access logs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: TBH, I don't think it is related to Go; I think it seems related to some weird configurations of Chrome.

Comment: Use Chromes Developer Tools to see whats happening

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running chrome from a different host, yes? (based on the fact that it shows an IP addr that isn't localhost)

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:9000", nil))
```

This means: listen specifically on 127.0.0.1:9000 (assuming your hosts file still has localhost assigned to 127.0.0.1 as is the default)

There's no way to hit that from another box.

Change to:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil))
```

Which will cause the go server to listen on all addresses of the machine it runs on.

Or are you saying that in chrome you type "localhost:9000" and it redirects to 16.155.255.10/apache-default from the same machine you tried IE on?

Comment: Yes, when I type "localhost:9000", it redirects to 16.155.255.10/apache-default. The IE, chrome, and web application all run on one notebook computer.

Comment: that's very odd.  Only think I can think of is that your chrome is setup with some kind of proxy or something.   Good luck figuring it out

Comment: In case this helps, 16.155.255.10 is an hp.com address.  Guessing your notebook is hp brand.  I'd assume there's a plugin or some kind of proxy that is intercepting your requests in chrome but not IE.  If you manually upgraded to Windows 10, HP's settings might have gotten dropped from IE, but chrome would have kept its settings.